# Similarity Index between 2 spectrograms

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

So I want to get the similarity index between 2D arrays representing 2 singers' voices. 
I read my mp3 files with `pydub`.
AudioFunctions.py

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment

class SongData():
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.audio = AudioSegment.from_file(path).set_channels(1)
        self.rate, self.data = self.audio.frame_rate, np.array(self.audio.get_array_of_samples())
        self.length = len(self.data)
        self.duration = self.audio.duration_seconds
        self.time = np.linspace(0, self.duration, self.length)
        self.freq = np.linspace(0, self.rate / 2, int(self.length / 2))
        self.fftArray = fft(self.data)
        self.fftArrayPositive = self.fftArray[:self.length // 2]
        self.fftArrayNegative = np.flip(self.fftArray[self.length // 2:])
        self.fftArrayAbs = np.abs(self.fftArray)
        self.fftPlotting = self.fftArrayAbs[: self.length // 2]


def song2data(path):
    songClass = SongData(path)
    return songClass


def getFirstData(songArr, time):
    selectedData = songArr[:int(time*44100)]
    return selectedData
```

And this is my code to get the data of 2 songs and get their spectrograms...

main.py

```py
from AudioFunctions import *
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa
import sklearn
from scipy import spatial
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity



songClass1 = song2data("sia1.mp3")
songClass2 = song2data("sia2.mp3")

# print(songClass.data)
# print(songClass.rate)
# print(songClass.duration)
# print(songClass.length)

songArray = getFirstData(songClass1.data, 120)
songArray2 = getFirstData(songClass2.data, 120)


frequencies, times, spectrogram = signal.spectrogram(songArray, 44100)
frequencies2, times2, spectrogram2 = signal.spectrogram(songArray2, 44100)

# print(frequencies)
spec = spectrogram.flatten()
spec2 = spectrogram2.flatten()


result = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(spec, spec2)
print(result)
```

The result represents a simliarity index between the 2 voices. However, it gives me low number (0.133) when comparing between 2 songs of the same singer(Sia).

Song 1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1svV0Ry_lNaEA9Z8c61t3S25XCSgIv6sW/view

Song 2:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ToKQo2MERBbxZezqDcEtEE2dhgmH-wus/view

Is there any problem in my logic ? Or this result could be logic for some cases?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a necro answer as yes in terms of spectrogram that is a time line of frequencies played by intensity the 2 different songs will be totally different and yes your logic is flawed